# How to select all same prefix columns along with other columns in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample pandas dataframe as follows:

```
delme = {
    "c1": [1, 2, 3],
    "c2": ["he", "she", "he"],
    "c3": [1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
    "pre_c1": ["x1", "x2", "x3"],
    "pre_c2": ["y1", "y2", "y3"],
    "pre_c3": ["z1", "z2", "z3"],
    "npre_c1": ["x1", "x2", "x3"],
    "npre_c2": ["y1", "y2", "y3"]
}

delmedf = pd.DataFrame(delme)

c1  c2  c3  pre_c1  pre_c2  pre_c3  npre_c1 npre_c2
1   he  1.3     x1      y1      z1       x1      y1
2   she 1.4     x2      y2      z2       x2      y2
3   he  1.5     x3      y3      z3       x3      y3
```

I want to select all columns with prefix `pre_` and `npre_` along with column `c3` from the `delmedf` dataframe. How do I do that?

So far I have tried to capture them individually and then merging them with `axis=1` as follows:

```
df1 = delmedf[delmedf.columns[(pd.Series(delmedf.columns).str.contains("pre_"))]]
df2= delmedf[[c2]]
data_X = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

But the above approach fails whenever I want to introduce another `str.contains("npre_")` condition as follows:
`df1 = delmedf[delmedf.columns[(pd.Series(delmedf.columns).str.contains("pre_")) or (pd.Series(delmedf.columns).str.contains("npre_"))]]`

The error I am getting with the above statement is:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `delmedf.filter(regex='pre|c3')` ?

Comment: @Datanovice In general you need co add ^ and $ to regex: `delmedf.filter(regex='^npre|^pre|^c3$')`. But solution is great)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
m=delmedf.columns.str.contains('pre_')|(delmedf.columns=='c3')
delmedf[delmedf.columns[m]]
```

---

**Output**

```
    c3 pre_c1 pre_c2 pre_c3 npre_c1 npre_c2
0  1.3     x1     y1     z1      x1      y1
1  1.4     x2     y2     z2      x2      y2
2  1.5     x3     y3     z3      x3      y3
```

Answer (score 1):

And one more option :)

```
selected_columns = [k for k in delmedf.columns if (k=='c3' or k[:4]=='pre_' or k[:5]=='npre_')]
new_delmedf = delmedf[selected_columns]
```

Result:

```
    c3 pre_c1 pre_c2 pre_c3 npre_c1 npre_c2
0  1.3     x1     y1     z1      x1      y1
1  1.4     x2     y2     z2      x2      y2
2  1.5     x3     y3     z3      x3      y3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
df.loc[:,np.ndarray.flatten(df.columns.str.extract(r'(^[n]?pre_.*|c3)').dropna().to_numpy())]                                                                                        

    c3 pre_c1 pre_c2 pre_c3 npre_c1 npre_c2
0  1.3     x1     y1     z1      x1      y1
1  1.4     x2     y2     z2      x2      y2
2  1.5     x3     y3     z3      x3      y3
```